# Find user with role (list of roles) who has exactly these roles from list and no other

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

Description of problem;

I have model of user with set of Roles (many to many relacion).
I would like to pick from database (MySQL) user who have exactly this roles which i askin (no more no less).

This is my query (doesn't work properly) if i looking for users with roles Admin and User:

```
select * from login.user u join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id join role r on ur.role_id = r.id where r.name in ('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')
```

Equivalent from Hibernate (NativeQuerty);

```
select * from user u join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id join role r on ur.role_id = r.id where r.name in (:roles)
```

This query return users who have roles Admin **or** User.
I am after Admin **and** User in this case.

If ask user with Admin role I would like have users who have only Admin roles.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are basically saying "give me any user who has either 'ROLE_ADMIN' or 'ROLE_USER' or both" in your query. If you specify only the role you are interested in you will get the results necessary.

This returns only admins for example:

```
select * from login.user u join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id join role r on ur.role_id = r.id where r.name in ('ROLE_ADMIN')
```